# How to get base url in apex when executed through portal user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

Following are the two URL's which I have in my Org

base / Force.com URL - https://aura-venky-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com

Community URL - https://venky-partner-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/community2/s/

when I run `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` the statement returns current instance URL. Here my question is how do I get force.com URL when I'm in the community.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? have you encoutnered any problems? I would suggest you update your post with your current code to further increase your chances of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **getCurrentRequestUrl**.
It returns the page/community/instacne the request was fired.

```
URL.getCurrentRequestUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Earlier I wasn't clear in my question.